# How many Google Analytics custom variables & advanced segments for each account, property & profile?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, data

Google changes this often and I'm having a hard time finding it in the GA documentation.

What are the limits for custom variables and advanced segments?

Are they specified at the account, property, or profile levels in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitations to your question are as follows:

> The total combined length of any custom variable name and value may not exceed 128 characters.
>
> Note: Google Analytics Premium accounts have 50 custom variables available.

- [Custom Variables Limit with Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#varTypes)
- [Google Analytics Premium](http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/)
- [Limits to advanced segmentation in Google Analytics](http://www.cardinalpath.com/limits-to-advanced-segmentation-in-google-analytics/)

  > I’ve found that I can only create 100 advanced segments at a time. That may sound like a lot, but when you have more than a few Google Analytics accounts, it’s easy to start creating a lot of segments for yourself.

I hope this answers your question completely. Best wishes!

Comment: How many does a non-Premium account have?

Comment: This explains the limitations of non-Premium accounts: http://www.customreportsharing.com/topic/53-what-are-the-absolute-limits-for-google-analytics/

Comment: On that site, the limit for advanced segments is reported as, "200 per account"

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this - [Google Analytics Limits](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0Ah7aF1naMKQLdHh1Z2IxbU8xeHNOZEZVamdhRnBidXc&hl=en&single=true&gid=0&output=html). I work as a technical analyst at an analytics agency and this is something very similar to what we use as reference.

**Custom Variable Slots**

- Standard (ga.js) - 5
- Universal (analytics.js) - 40 (20 custom dimensions/20 custom metrics)
- Premium - 50

**Advanced Segments**

- Standard/Premium - 100

Comment: Welcome to the site - there's a need for more analysts here. It might be helpful to quote the helpful bits from the link you provided, in case it goes down in the future.

Comment: dan, I've gone and updated my original post. Thanks